# How to install wubi alongside Windows 8?

Tags: boot, windows, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

So, I tried to install wubi alongside my Windows 8. I did all the steps shown in the tutorial.

Problem is, when I boot, it won't allow me to access the Ubuntu OS. I've googled it and it seems like Windows 8 has some protection against other OS, didn't get it quite well...

Anyway, I'm looking for a way to have Wubi in my Windows 8 machine. I wouldn't like to make a dual boot and partition my HD for several reasons, so I'd rather go for wubi...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wubi works with Windows 8 but not if you have the UEFI boot with GPT disk (computers with secure boot all have this).

Comment: Is this going to be fixed?

Comment: Here's the bug report. That's the best place to ask: http://pad.lv/694242

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).