# Wubi install freezes 3/4 through

Tags: installation, wubi

I downloaded Ubuntu on a USB stick, then the Windows installer, and ran `wubi.exe`. When I rebooted to complete the installation, it froze 3/4 of the way through. After 30 minutes of waiting I removed the USB stick. I've tried again and the same thing happens.

Will it harm my computer in any way?

Comment: Are you using the Windows Installer and do you have Windows 8? See the comments on http://askubuntu.com/questions/216961/how-to-install-wubi-alongside-windows-8

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/144237/how-do-i-uninstall-ubuntu-wubi on how to unintall WUBI. There is minimal chance of damage, as WUBI puts everything in a big file instead of in dedicated partitions.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what the cause of this is, but it seems to affect 32-bit installs from the ISO only. There have been a growing number of reports, but not a lot of detailed follow-up feedback. The suggestions are to:

1. Run `wubi.exe` standalone (without any DVD/USB containing Ubuntu present) to allow it to download the diskimage install (which does not have this problem), or...
2. Install using the 64-bit media (although this doesn't currently work for the latest 12.04.2 wubi.exe unless you use the patched version here: [people.canonical.com/~evand/wubi/precise/wubi-r273-signed.exe](http://people.canonical.com/~evand/wubi/precise/wubi-r273-signed.exe))
3. Review [bug 1182805](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1182805) and see whether you have any information you can add (see more information on this below)

Other people have found switching to the console and back can get it re-started: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

When Ubuntu freezes you should reboot safely by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrntScr</kbd> and then pressing the following keys (pause between each one): <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>

Here is some general advice:
Hard reboots or shutdowns can damage the file systems. In your case, you can run `chkdsk` from windows to make sure there is no corruption.

You can drop to a terminal when this happens <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and see if there's anything interesting in the logs: `cat /var/log/syslog` or zip up your logs and [file a new bug](http://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+filebug) or - if suitable - attach to the existing bug mentioned above:

```
sudo zip -r /host/ubuntu/logs.zip /var/log
```

That command creates a zip file you can find from Windows in `C:\ubuntu\logs.zip` (assuming you installed on `C:`. Attach that to your bug report.

If you have a graphics card that requires a closed source driver, you could also try booting with `nomodeset`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a disaster. I once had similar problem. The problem was solved when i burned a brand new bootable CD, using the Ubuntu disk image i downloaded from http://www.ubuntu.com/download section. You should boot up from your CD/DVD drive.

Comment: What should i do now? Return to windows? How to proceed, so not to cause any damage? Thanx!