# How can I install wubi with more than 30 GB?

Tags: 12.10, wubi, windows-8, hp-pavilion

I want to install Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 8 with Wubi. Can I somehow install Ubuntu (wubi) with more than 30 GB of space? I have a HP Pavilion g7 1303 (x64).

Comment: Wubi is not meant to be a full on install of Ubuntu, it's purpose is to give users a chance to try Ubuntu. That said, limitations of software and other things you can't use more than 30 GB.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/216961/how-to-install-wubi-alongside-windows-8 and that link has mention of a bug: [Wubi does not check if Windows boots using UEFI](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/694242)