# How can I get Ubuntu to work alongside windows 8?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

I'm not really good with computers, so I have no idea what's going on. What I do know is that I absolutely hate Windows 8 and in every desperate attempt, from trying to install windows 2000 to trying to install Ubuntu, all has failed.
I downloaded Ubuntu, installed with Wubi, and everytime I try to start it it says that a file is missing.
I understand this has something to do with my safe boot or whatever, but I have no idea how to turn that off. I thought I turned it off, but Ubuntu won't start so I probably did it wrong.
Can someone please give me an idiots guide on making this work because I swear if I have to put up with Windows 8 for another day I will throw myself and my Laptop out a window.

Comment: Don't -1 this question. We should support people in turning them from the dark side :)

Comment: @bioShark It shows absolutely no research effort. The duplicate question is really easy to stumble upon using either Google or the search here. It should also have been popping up while writing the title of this question.

Comment: True, but I absolutely loved her last phrase :)

Comment: "it shows no research effort" wait are you kidding me is that a joke or what because literally i spent hours on google yesterday trying to figure this out alright. i almost turned to 4chan for advice this is literally my last resort.

Comment: @Molly Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm not saying you didn't put any effort in it. It's just not in your question, like "tried this, stumbled upon this question, tried that suggestion, failed on step 2 with error xyz, tried another approach", etc. We expect users to write about this rather than frustrations. See also the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Comment: @Molly the link Eliah Kagan provided in his first comment should help you. Another solution would be to return the laptop and buy one without Win 8 on it.

Comment: @bioShark: we should encourage users to vote honestly, and that includes down-voting. This question as it stands now just can't be answered. It could be any one of a number of things. All we know is that the OP gets a "file is missing error". That is nothing to go on. I really hate downvoting newcomers, especially if you can tell that they've just had a really frustrating troubleshooting session, but Ask Ubuntu isn't the place for questions that are only useful to one person. And we want people to upvote and downvote questions, so that good questions can find good answers quickly.

Comment: @Flimm Seems to me it can be answered [and has](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system). **Molly**: If that doesn't help, please expand this question to include detailed information about everything you've tried and what happened. If there were error messages, please include them in their entirety. (You can try a method again to get the exact error, if you didn't take it down when you saw it the first time.)

Comment: If you have trouble understanding how to use the instructions I linked to, or any other instructions, please edit your question to explain *that* in as much detail as possible. We might close this question because, to the extent to which it may not be a duplicate of that question, it probably cannot (as Flimm says) be answered. However if you edit your question to improve it or give more information, and it's closed, you can flag and/or comment to request reopening

Answer (score 2):

Wubi does not work with Windows 8 if you have UEFI-enabled hardware. [How to install wubi alongside Windows 8?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216961/how-to-install-wubi-alongside-windows-8)  If you have UEFI-enabled hardware, there is no solution for installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8. I'd recommend either building your own computer or buying one from [system76](https://www.system76.com/). It sure beats jumping out of a window.